# Angular 5 Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, angular, angular5, angular4-router

I'm working with angular 5. I have added scripts required in index.html file for revolution slider. It is working fine when loading website. But when I'm clicking to next page and go back to home page jquery showing me error and revolution slider not working.

Here are the jquery files I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.templateaccess.plugins.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.templateaccess.revolution.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/script.js"></script>
```

I'm getting error in jquery.min.js file. Can anybody help me to resolve the issue so this jquery load with the routing.

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: you should add those inside `index.html` file in root

Comment: Here is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Function.each (VM3237 jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Read this article it might help [angular and jquery](https://gist.github.com/Meligy/a26ed355a8db44b49174a55b9d26d575)

Comment: Yes these are included in index.html file its working fine. But not when you going to next page and coming back to home page

Comment: I go through all the articles but did not get solution

Comment: You should show us more code to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is index.html file:<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.templateaccess.plugins.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jquery.templateaccess.revolution.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/script.js"></script>
You can check revolution slider: http://www.dcodes.net/2/docs/sliders6.html